# How to get list of all database from NpgsqlConnection in a combobox using c#.net

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, npgsql

Im trying to develop a console application and i need to know the all database list name .but this code is not working .This is my code:

```
public static List<string> AllNpgsqlDatabaseName()
         {
            List<string> li = new List<string>();
            NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=localhost;Username=root;Password=root;");
            connection.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT name from sys.databases";
            NpgsqlDataReader Reader;

            Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                string row = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    row += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
                li.Add(row);
            }

            connection.Close();
            return li;
        }
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose of your connection (and commands and reader!) with using, otherwise an exception will cause a connection leak

Comment: OK thanks man, for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database
```